# I will have a masters in accounting and I want to study the psychology of money, so I'm looking to get a phd in psychology, do I have to start over?

Tags: degree

I want to learn how money impacts people's behavior and use that information to help people build wealth. I already have a working knowledge of the psychology of money and I am working towards my CPA license. I'm most interested in helping people reach their financial goals. I feel conducting clinic trials will help me accomplish that goal, but my background is accounting, not psychology. I could do both, but I don't know if that means I have to start over for a second masters or if I can use my experience and desired area of psychological study as a basis for a PHD.

Comment: What part of the world are you in? Where do you anticipate being employed to conduct these clinical trials (university, hospital, …)?

Comment: What would be a clinic trial in this case? I don't see a medical intervention.